# CakeEmail- Is there a way to send an array instead of var

Tags: email, cakephp-2.3

I am usinf the cakeEmail fonction.

I am used to do like this (see viewVar)

```
$mail->from(authComponent::user('email'))
->to($this->Session->read('Site.email'))
->subject($this->Session->read('Site.name').' : New order No. '.$this->Basket->id)
->emailFormat('html')
->template('orderconfirmation')
->viewVars(array('title'=>'vlaue'))
->send();
```

I nedd to send a lot of data as the data of several boght product. It can have one product but it can have 10 product.

Then, I would like to send an array $detailOfProducts, in that way, in my mail template, I am going to use a loop to display the content.

```
I tried to change like this but without success
    $mail->from(authComponent::user('email'))
    ->to($this->Session->read('Site.email'))
    ->subject($this->Session->read('Site.name').' : New order No. '.$this->Basket->id)
    ->emailFormat('html')
    ->template('orderconfirmation')
    ->viewVars($detailOfProducts)
    ->send();
```

Do you know a solution?

Thank a lot

Answer (score 0):

Send them like u send the vars to your view ..

```
$mail->from(authComponent::user('email'))
->to($this->Session->read('Site.email'))
->subject($this->Session->read('Site.name').' : New order No. '.$this->Basket->id)
->emailFormat('html')
->template('orderconfirmation')
->viewVars(array('details'=>$detailOfProducts))
->send();
```

Your view code will be ..

```
<?php echo $detail[0]['Model']['field']; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got the answer!!!
Sorry, I should have tried before.

```
echo count($basketItems);
echo $basketItems[0]['name'];
```

then with the result of count(), I can make a loop to display all. I am going to try this now.
Many thank for you help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer: (It's into a loop)

```
<?php echo $basketItems[$i]['name']; ?>
```

Thank for your help!!!!